# sending data over sms to cloud server

Tags: sql-server, google-cloud-platform, udp, sms, gsm

Is there any way we can send data over sms to any cloud server.using GSM. I searched online but find only ways to send data to any server from gsm module is trough GPRS. but i want my SMS to get stored on the cloud server directly. I have seen like we send balance request sms to tollfree numbers to get our balance info, they must be using servers to store the sms and send the proper response to user.so i was wondering if i may use this feature of there to send any small data over sms and store it to cloud server.does any such mechanism exists.please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Twilio [[1]](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/quickstart/programmable-sms-functions), a third-party, for sending/receiving SMS to/from Google App Engine [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/using-sms-and-voice-services-via-twilio#receiving_an_sms).

This tutorial [[3]](https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-functions-twilio-sms) shows using Google Cloud Functions and Twilio to reply to an SMS message.